# No Extension Method for Client Name in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Given the code below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using NetworksApi.TCP.CLIENT;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Form1 client;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void textBox2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             if (textBox3.Text!= "" &&textBox4.Text!="")
             {
                 client = new Form1();
                 client.ClientName = textBox4.Text;
                 client.ServerIp = textBox3.Text;
                 client.Connect();
             }
             else
             {
                 MessageBox.Show("Fill it completely");
             }
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Environment.Exit(System.Environment.ExitCode);
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error message whenever I try to compile:

> 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1' does not contain a definition for
>   ClientName and no extension method 'ClientName' accepting a first
>   argument of type.

Do you have any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no ClientName property on a Windows Form class. However, since you are inheriting from Form, you can add one. But that doesn't make sense either. Are you sure you want a variable of type `Form1` to have properties for `ClientName`, `ServerIP`, and a method for `Connect()`? Much more likely you want either some other pre-existing class or to make your own.

```
public class ClientService
{
    public string ClientName {get; set;}
    public string ServerIp {get; set;}

    public void Connect()
    {
        //logic here
    }
}
```

And change your UI logic to

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox3.Text) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox4.Text))
{
    var client = new ClientService();
    client.ClientName = textBox4.Text;
    client.ServerIp = textBox3.Text;
    client.Connect();
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Fill it completely");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the documentation for the `Form` class in .NET: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form(v=vs.110).aspx

Notice there's no member for `ClientName` listed. You cannot reference it because it doesn't exist.